# Creating an adstock/ carryover function for Panel Data

Tags: r

I'm working on a Marketing Mix Model with cross-sectional data and trying to fit a function that would apply the AdStock/decay transformation for each unit separately.

Adstock transformation assumes that advertising does not affect customers immediately, but is distributed in time. For example: if we generate 100 GRPs in week 1 and the decay rate is 0.5, only 50 will affect sales in week 1, 25 in week 2, 12,5 in week 3 and so on.

I am able to write a loop for the aggregated data, but struggle with fitting it into a function of media variable and decay rate running separately for each unit in cross-sectional data.

```
# Preparing some data

dt1 <- data.frame(time = c(1:8), var = c(100,0,0,0,200,0,0,0))

# defining AdStock rate

adstock_rate <- 0.5

# A loop for adstocked variable

for (i in 1:length(dt1$var)){

  if (i == 1) {
    dt1$adstocked_advertising[i] = dt1$var[i] * adstock_rate }

  else {


    dt1$adstocked_advertising[i] = adstock_rate * dt1$var[i] + (1 - adstock_rate) * dt1$adstocked_advertising[i-1]
  } }
```

And the result is

```
  time var adstocked_advertising
1    1 100              50.00000
2    2   0              25.00000
3    3   0              12.50000
4    4   0               6.25000
5    5 200             103.12500
6    6   0              51.56250
7    7   0              25.78125
8    8   0              12.89062
```

How can I write a function that would work in case of cross-sectional data? For example in this data set:

```
# Cross-sectional data

dt <- data.frame(location = rep(letters[1:2], each = 4), time = rep(1:4, 2), var = c(100,0,0,0,200,0,0,0))

# Data Frame

  location time var
1        a    1 100
2        a    2   0
3        a    3   0
4        a    4   0
5        b    1 200
6        b    2   0
7        b    3   0
8        b    4   0
```

Now I need to write the AdstockTransform(var, adstock_rate) function that would apply the loop from the first example to each location separately. This is important as adstock_rate parameter should be then optimized with methods like nlsLM.

I would really appreciate some help.

EDIT: Thank you, Parfait, your solution is a great help. Do you think it is possible to use it as one function? I'll try to explain why it is so important with the semi - solution using the filter function.

```
library(bayesm)
library(minpack.lm)
library(dplyr)

data(cheese)

# Function that describes both the AdStock and diminishing returns

adstockTransform <- function(x, as, beta){
  stats::filter( 1/(1+exp(-beta*x)), as, method = "recursive")
}

mmm.data <- cheese %>%
  group_by(RETAILER) %>%
  mutate(log.volume = log(VOLUME), log.price = log(PRICE), adstock= adstockTransform(DISP, as, beta))

# Optimization of the parameters

fit <- nlsLM(log.volume ~  const + B1*adstockTransform(DISP, as, beta) + B2*log.price,
             start = c(const = 10, B1 = 0.5, as = 0.2, beta = 2, B2 = -3),
             lower = c(const = 5, B1 = 0.2, as = 0.1, beta = 1.5, B2 = -5),
             upper = c(const = 12, B1 = 2, as = 0.4, beta = 6, B2 = -2),
             data=mmm.data)

summary(fit)

# Output

Formula: log.volume ~ const + B1 * adstockTransform(DISP, as, beta) + 
    B2 * log.price

Parameters:
      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
const  9.77943    0.11588  84.392  < 2e-16 ***
B1     0.40081    0.11288   3.551 0.000387 ***
as     0.40000    0.12625   3.168 0.001542 ** 
beta   6.00000    2.86959   2.091 0.036583 *  
B2    -2.00000    0.05896 -33.923  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7709 on 5550 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 3 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
```

Of course - in order to find the best parameters for, let's say, Fixed Effects Model I should demean the data before the optimization; but it is a simple example.

Even though the filter function is helpful, it suffers from two major drawbacks:

1) Using it is hard to justify in case of modeling the sales variable. The geometric decay fits other vars - like brand awareness - much better

2) It is impossible to encode it with brms package

Of course, it is almost perfectly correlated with the "desired" adstock transformation, but it would be great to skip this additional filter -> adstock step.

Comment: Hi Adam, I have also been trying to figure out Marketing Mix Model. I am very new to this kind of modeling and so far the work I have done does not look very promising. It looks like that you have a very deep understanding of it. I was hoping if there is a way we can discuss this offline that would be very help. I understand that it may be much of a ask but just thought of reaching out to you and giving it a try. Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `by` to subset your data by location and run needed calculation via a defined function, then `rbind` all data frame objects:

```
# Preparing some data
dt <- data.frame(location = rep(letters[1:2], each = 4), 
                 time = rep(1:4, 2), 
                 var = c(100,0,0,0,200,0,0,0))

# defining AdStock rate
adstock_rate <- 0.5

# define function to calculate column
calc_decay <- function(sub) {    
   # A loop for adstocked variable
   for (i in 1:length(sub$var)){
     if (i == 1) { sub$adstocked_advertising[i] <- sub$var[i] * adstock_rate }
     else { sub$adstocked_advertising[i] <- sub$var[i] * adstock_rate + 
                                             (1 - adstock_rate) * sub$adstocked_advertising[i-1] }
  }    
  return(sub)
}

# by call
df_list <- by(dt1, dt1$Location, calc_decay)

# rbind all elements    
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

**Final Output**

```
final_df

#   location time var adstocked_advertising
# 1        a    1 100                 50.00
# 2        a    2   0                 25.00
# 3        a    3   0                 12.50
# 4        a    4   0                  6.25
# 5        b    1 200                100.00
# 6        b    2   0                 50.00
# 7        b    3   0                 25.00
# 8        b    4   0                 12.50
```

Comment: Thank you, Parfait, it does work! Do you think it is possible to use this solution in a single function? I will edit the topic to show what I mean.

Comment: You might be straying from your original question which this solution attempts to answer: *Now I need to write the `AdstockTransform(var, adstock_rate)` function that would apply the loop from the first example to each location separately.* Do note: you can call *any* function that receives a data frame into `by`.

Comment: In fact, you appear to be asking a non-programming, modeling question which is best reserved on [StatsExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [DataScienceExchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In fact - your function helped me to solve the problem. I'll post it a bit later. Thank you, Parfrait.